# String manipulation using C- Segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run a program which will choose the second word from a string .
bur every time i try to run the program it shows me segmentation fault .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
    // Read only region start

    char* secondWordUpperCase(char* input1)
    {
        // Read only region end
        // Write code here
        int len,i,j,k,pos=0;
        char *str;
        len=strlen(input1);
        str= malloc(len+1);
        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
            if(*(input1+i)==" ")
            {
                pos=i+1;
            }
        }
        for(i=pos;*(input1+i)!=" ";i++)
        {
            *(str+i)=*(input1+i);
        }
        *(str+(i+1))="\0";
        return str;
    }
```

i run this program on mettl online compiler so i don't have the driver code . can anyone guide me for the mistake i have been making,That would be a great help to me as i am a newbie.

Comment: You are using double-quotes, which denote strings, where you probably intend to use single-quotes to compare characters.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons the problem still persists if i tend ti use single qoutes.

Comment: Did you use single-quotes in all three spots?  Also, your code would be more readable if you used array notation instead of all this pointer arithmetic and dereferencing.  e.g. `*(input1+i)`-->`input[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash happens because you are looking for `" "` (a string literal with a single space) instead of `' '` (a character literal for space). In addition, starting `i` at `pos` in the second loop leaves the initial `pos-1` characters uninitialized. If you would like to trim the spaces, use this loop:

```
for (i=0 ; *(input1+i) != ' ' ; i++) {
    *(str+i)=*(input1+pos+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing with a pointer where you want to compare to a char.

```
if(*(input1+i)==" ")
```

->

```
if(*(input1+i)==' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The second loop can run past the input buffer (and cause a buffer overrun) when the input has only one or 2 words. Indeed that 2nd loop will only stop at next space, which won't exist in those 2 cases.

In addition, you probably want to write the detected 2nd word at the beginning of str and thus not assign to *str instead of *(str+1).

Finally, the tests in both loop compare a charecter with a pointer to the a string " ". Those don't cause the segmentation fault but it's probably not the intended behaviour.